# Fatal Java error on starting Cassandra on Windows

Tags: cassandra

When I start Cassandra 3.11.6 using `cassandra -f` from `cmd`, I get error

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000010014ed4, pid=29376, tid=0x0000000000007aa4
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_281-b09) (build 1.8.0_281-b09)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.281-b09 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [sigar-amd64-winnt.dll+0x14ed4]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\MChadha\Documents\manu\apache-cassandra-3.11.6-for-scalardb\bin\hs_err_pid29376.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

What might be causing this error?

My Java version is

```
java version "1.8.0_281"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_281-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.281-b09, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue with Java. I was using java 1.8.0_271 and getting same error. Had to downgrade to 1.8.0_251 to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention Windows version. However you can check Java if this is a bug as mentioned in https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8182156

Or try to enable minidumps in your Windows envionment.